# Erro au renderizar tela em aplicação pimefaces - NullPointException

Tags: jsf-2.2, cdi, primefaces-5.2

Uu método, ao ser chamado dá `NullPointException`.

Tem uma expressão que valida quando for editar aparece cabeçalho "Edição de Produto", se Novo cadastro aparece "novo". No `cadastroProdutoBean.java` tem método `boolean isEditando`, nele está dando erro.

Método:

```
public boolean isEditando() {
    return this.produto.getId() != null; 
}
```

Expressão no xhtml:

```
#{cadastroProdutoBean.editando ? 'Edição de Produto' : 'Novo Produto'}
```

Segue o log:

```
 GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml: Error reading 'editando' on type com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.CadastroProdutoBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.CadastroProdutoBean.isEditando(CadastroProdutoBean.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:184)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 32 more

01:32:40.663 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR com.oliveira.pedidovenda.util.jsf.JsfExceptionHandler - Erro de sistema: /produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml: Error reading 'editando' on type com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.CadastroProdutoBean
javax.el.ELException: /produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml: Error reading 'editando' on type com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.CadastroProdutoBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651) [javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.CadastroProdutoBean.isEditando(CadastroProdutoBean.java:106) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99) ~[el-api.jar:2.2.FR]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:184) ~[jasper-el.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:44) ~[jasper-el.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184) ~[jasper-el.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) ~[weld-servlet-2.3.2.Final.jar:2.3.2.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Olá, Adriano. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Da próxima vez, procure formatar melhor sua questão, colocando corretamente o código e o log como fiz acima, senão fica muito difícil de entender o que está acontecendo. Além disso, procure não usar comentários para adicionar código ou informações. Você deve editar a sua pergunta e acrescentar lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A expressão no método `isEditando` vai lançar um NPE se o atributo `produto` for nulo.

Para corrigir o problema, ou você deve garantir que o produto esteja selecionado antes do método ser executado ou verificar se há valor na variável, por exemplo:

```
return this.produto != null && this.produto.getId() != null;
```

Comment: Valeu pela dica sou novo "stackoverflow" e em fóruns,  gostei da dica foi favorável, erro não está mais aparecendo, mas não está carregando dados na edição, como se não estivesse passando método, aparece id selecionado mas campos em branco, expressão não funciona sempre novo produto em tela edição, vou fazer mais algumas tentativas ver o que está errado, se tiver alguma dica fico no aguardo obrigado!!!.

Comment: @Adriano verifique o escopo do bean. Se é de sessão ou Request.  Pode estar recria do o bean e perdendo o valor do produto selecionado.

Comment: Beleza agora deu certo, valeu; estava com ViewScoped:    'import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;'    mudei para ViewScoped:    'import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;'    excelente muito obrigado!!!

Comment: olá utluiz estou com probleminha retorn null ao savar produto tem como me ajudar

Comment: OLá Utluiz estou com um problema retorn null ao salvar postei stack dê uma olhada. [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149546/retorno-nulo-ao-cadastrar-novo-produto-mas-quando-edito-consigo-salvar-n%C3%A3o-dar/149570#149570]